# What is the simplest way to obtain asymptotics of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(1+k)^2}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

In the middle of a proof, I have had to analyze the asymptototic behavior of
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)^2}\right] = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}\tag{1}
$$
where $X$ is Binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $1/2$. (I also had to handle $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)^4}\right]$, but let's start with the square).

Now, it is easy to compute
$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right], \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)(2+X)}\right]$, but (1) does not have any closed form (the hypergeometric function is *not* considered by me as a closed form).

I know that, as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)^2}\right] = \frac{4}{n^2} - \frac{4}{n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \tag{2}
$$
(see e.g. [1], which implies this but deals with general probability $p$ and power $r$ instead of $p=1/2$ and $r=2$), but that seems overkill.

> What is the simplest and most elegant way to derive (2)?

- Via a simple argument (concentration of the Binomial around $n/2+O(\sqrt{n})$) is it easy to show that is it $\Theta(1/n^2)$. Applying Jensen also shows a lower bound of $\frac{4}{n^2}+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$.
- via a still simple argument, involving comparing it to the (explicitly computable) $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)(2+X)}\right]$ and bounding the difference, it is not hard to show it is $\frac{4}{n^2} + \Theta\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$.

But that's not necessarily elegant, and also doesn't quite lead to (2) (I reckon the second approach can be made work, but it'll get messy, and will definitely not end up being a "proof from the book")

---

[1] Francisco Cribari-Neto, Nancy Lopes Garcia, and Klaus LP Vasconcellos. *A note on inverse moments of binomial variates.* Brazilian Review of Econometrics, 20(2):269–
277, 2000.

Comment: Have you tried using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula?

Comment: @MarkViola No, I haven't. I was afraid that'd get messy very quickly (for the sake of my argument, since I couldn't get a 4-line proof I just cited [1] and moved on to the rest)

Comment: have you tried generating functions? seems to work pretty smoothly..
start from $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}z^k$ and integrate...?

Comment: Following the suggestion by @tired, use $$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1 x^k\,dx\int_0^1 y^k\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (1+xy)^n\,dx\,dy
\end{align}$$

Comment: @tired That's probably where the hypergeometric function comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Answer.** If $p(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial of degree $d$ having no zero on $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0,1,\cdots\}$ and $m \geq d$, then we may expand

$$ \frac{1}{p(x)} = \sum_{k=d}^{m} \frac{c_k}{(x+1)\cdots(x+k)} + r(x),$$

where $c_k$'s are constants and $r(x)$ has no pole on $\mathbb{N}_0$ and satisfies $r(x) = \mathcal{O}(\lvert x\rvert^{-m-1})$ near $\infty$. Constants $c_k$'s may be determined by comparing Laurent expansions of both sides at $\infty$, or by clever algebraic manipulation in nice situations. Then it follows that

$$ \mathbf{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{p(X)}\bigg]
= \sum_{k=d}^{m} \frac{c_k 2^k}{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\right). $$

> **Example 1.** For each $m\geq2$, we have
>
> $$ \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} = \sum_{k=2}^{m} \frac{(k-2)!}{(x+1)\cdots(x+k)} + \frac{(m-1)!}{(x+1)^2(x+2)\cdots(x+m)} $$
>
> So
>
> $$ \mathbf{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\bigg] = \sum_{k=2}^{m} \frac{(k-2)!2^k}{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\right) $$

Similarly,

> **Example 2.** Comparing the Laurent expansion near $x=\infty$, we find that
>
> $$ \frac{1}{(x+1)^4} = \frac{1}{(x+1)\cdots(x+4)} + \frac{6}{(x+1)\cdots(x+5)} + r(x)$$
>
> where $r(x) = \frac{109 + 120 x + 35 x^2}{(x+1)^4(x+2)\cdots(x+5)}$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^{-6})$ as $x\to\infty$. This gives
>
> $$ \mathbf{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{(x+1)^4}\bigg] = \frac{16}{(n+1)\cdots(n+4)} + \frac{192}{(n+1)\cdots(n+5)} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right). $$

---

**Old Answer.** Write $X = Y+Z$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and $Y\sim\operatorname{Bin}\big(n-1,\frac{1}{2}\big)$ and $Z\sim\operatorname{Ber}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$. Then by conditioning on $Y$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+X)^2} \bigg]
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+Y)^2} + \frac{1}{(2+Y)^2} \bigg] \\
&= \mathbf{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+Y)(2+Y)} \bigg] + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{E}\bigg[ \bigg( \frac{1}{1+Y} - \frac{1}{2+Y} \bigg)^2 \bigg].
\end{align*}

Now using the probability generating function $f(z)=\mathbf{E}[z^Y] = \left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)^{n-1}$, for each $k = 1, 2, \cdots$ we check that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+Y)\cdots(k+Y)} \bigg]
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-z)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} f(z) \, dz \\
&= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} \frac{2^k}{(k-1)!} (1-w)^{k-1}w^{n-1}\,dw \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2^k}{(k-1)!} (1-w)^{k-1}w^{n-1}\,dw + \mathcal{O}_k(2^{-n}) \\
&= \frac{2^k (n-1)!}{(n+k-1)!} + \mathcal{O}_k(2^{-n}).
\end{align*}

Here, the implicit bounds depend only on $k$. In particular,

- $ \mathbf{E}\Big[ \frac{1}{(1+Y)(2+Y)} \Big] = \frac{4}{n(n+1)} + \mathcal{O}(2^{-n}) $,
- $ \mathbf{E}\Big[ \Big( \frac{1}{1+Y} - \frac{1}{2+Y} \Big)^2 \Big]
  = \mathbf{E}\Big[ \frac{1}{(1+Y)^2(2+Y)^2} \Big]
  \leq \mathbf{E}\Big[ \frac{6}{(1+Y)(2+Y)(3+Y)(4+Y)} \Big] = \mathcal{O}\Big(\frac{1}{n^4}\Big). $ Here, we utilized the simple inequality that if $x \geq 0$ and $0 < a < b$ then $\frac{a}{a+x} \leq \frac{b}{b+x}$.

Therefore it follows that

$$ \mathbf{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+X)^2} \bigg]
= \frac{4}{n(n+1)} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)
= \frac{4}{n^2} - \frac{4}{n^3} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right). $$

Comment: Nice. My brain is currently fried, but glancing at it it looks like a version of my second bullet, on steroids and with a dapper bow tie.

Comment: @ClementC. You are right. The new input here is the first equality that produces a better resolution of the remainder term.

Comment: Oh, I didn't say that as a criticism :) A very dapper bow tie.

Comment: @ClementC., Thank you. In fact, I also did not consider your comment as a criticism. :) I was quite sure that you already know most of the idea there.

Comment: also a  well deserved (+1)..i like this kind of probalistic arguments

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1 x^k\,dx\int_0^1 y^k\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\int_0^1\int_0^1 (1+xy)^n\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 \log(x)\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^n\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Observing that the term $\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^n$ in the integrand of $(1)$ decays rapidly away from $1$, we are motivated to expand the logarithm around $x=1$.  The integration of the first term reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2^n}\int_0^1 (1-x)(1+x)^n\,dx&=\frac{4-(n+3)2^{-n}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\\\
&=\frac4{n^2}-\frac{12}{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)
\end{align}$$

Continuing, the integration of the second term reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2^n}\int_0^1 \frac12 (1-x)^2(1+x)^n\,dx&=\frac{8-(n^2+7n+14)2^{-(n+1)}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\\\\
&=\frac8{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)
\end{align}$$

Putting all of this together, we have

$$\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}\sim \frac{4}{n^2}-\frac{4}{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

as was to be shown!

---

**NOTE:**

To make things more rigorous, let $\delta \in (0,1)$ and write

$$-\int_0^1 \log(x)\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^n\,dx=-\int_0^\delta \log(x)\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^n\,dx-\int_\delta^1 \log(x)\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^n\,dx\tag2$$

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ decays faster than any reciprocal power of $n$.  And for the second integral, there exist a number $\xi$, $\delta\le x<\xi<1$, such that

$$\log(x)=(x-1)-\frac12(x-1)^2+\frac1{3\xi^3}(x-1)^3$$

Bounds for the integral $\int_\delta^1 \frac{1}{3\xi^3}(x-1)^3(1+x)^n\,dx$ can easily be obtained to show that $\int_\delta^1 \frac{1}{3\xi^3}(x-1)^3(1+x)^n\,dx=O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$.

Comment: That looks neat indeed. For the sake of correctness, however, don't we also need to establish further that the order $\geq 3$ terms, all together, integrate to $O(1/n^4)$?

Comment: @ClementC. I checked the next terms contribution and it was $O(1/n^4)$.  I have not shown that the sum of the remaining terms are $(1/n^4)$.  Try splitting the integral as $\int_0^1=\int_0^\delta+\int_\delta^1$.

Comment: (I mean the contribution of the order-$\geq3$ terms in the expansion of the logarithm around $1$ after integration, not the contribution ofe the order-$\geq 3$ terms of the integrated order-$1$ and order-$2$ terms. My phrasing was a bit confusing)

Comment: Yes, I knew what you meant.  Choose some $\delta\in (0,1)$ and write the integral $\int_0^1=\int_0^\delta +\int_\delta^1$.  The integral over $x\in [0,\delta]$ clears decays like $(\frac{1+\delta}2)^n$.  So, we don't care about that term.   For the integration over $[\delta,1]$, you can simply apply the MVT and convince yourself of the expansion.

Comment: @ClementC. I've added a note that should help make things rigorous.

Comment: Thanks. I may be splitting hair or confused -- what is $\xi$ the same of all $x\in[\delta,1]$, instead of being function of $x$ (which then is still amenable very simple to an upper bound, and we end up integrating $\int_\delta^1 \frac{1}{\delta^3} [\cdots]$ for the upper bound)?

Comment: I've corrected.  Yes, $\delta\le x<\xi<1$.  And certainly $\xi$ depends on $x$.

Comment: glad someone has taken the gf method (+1). i would personally use a 1-variable gf, but that is just a matter of taste :-)